# How query data use offset in kusto (Azure Data Explorer) KQL for paging

Tags: sql, azure, azure-data-explorer, kql, adx

How can I realize below SQL query use offset for paging query in KQL.

```
select * from testtable where code = '88580' limit 1000 offset 111
```

I can't find any function in KQL can like the offset in SQL

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that for pagination Kusto has [Stored query results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/stored-query-results#pagination) which is used for pagination, and allows you to filter easily on the row numbers.

I'm not aware of `offset` in KQL, but you can add a row_number, and filter by it:

```
let testtable = datatable(code: int) [
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
    11, 12, 13, 14, 15
];
testtable
| where code > 0
| serialize
| extend _row=row_number()
| limit 1000
| where _row > 10
```

Comment: If you already linked to the right place, it would be better to do the extra step and supply an answer that uses the sored query results.